# Insert numbers into list given another list of index numbers

Tags: python, list

I'm looking to insert a list of numbers (firstNumberList) into specific points in another list (secondNumberList) according to a list of index numbers (indexNumberList).

```
indexNumberList = [1, 2, 5, 8]
firstNumberList = [0, 0, 0, 0]
secondNumberList = [ 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 9, 9, 12, 12, 18, 19, 18, 9]
```

I've tried the following list comprehension but it returns `[none, none, none, none]`

```
result =[secondNumberlist.insert(indexNumberList[elem],firstNumberList[elem]) for elem in range(len(indexNumberList))]
```

ultimately the output should look like this

```
[ 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 2, 4, 0, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 9, 9, 12, 12, 18, 19, 18, 9]
```

Comment: Mic, good first question in my view, nice and clear, thanks!

Comment: It is not clear. It first says he wants to insert in another list, and then in the code creates a new one...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Whether a new list is built or the original one modified (perhaps either is okay), it's a lot better than most first questions as it has input, desired output and a coding attempt plus problem description

Comment: By the way, @Mic, your own solution works. The problem is that you are inspecting `result` which holds the return values of `insert` which is always `None`. But while you are creating the `result` list you are also changing `secondNumberList` which is actually how you expect it.

Comment: @Tomerikoo, Thanks for the insight! You are correct. By printing secondNumberList I did indeed have the correct solution but was looking in the wrong place by printing result. I'll have to watch out for that in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
indexNumberList = [1, 2, 5, 8]
firstNumberList = [0, 0, 0, 0]
secondNumberList = [3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 9, 9, 12, 12, 18, 19, 18, 9]

for i, v in zip(indexNumberList, firstNumberList):
    secondNumberList = secondNumberList[:i] + [v] + secondNumberList[i:]

print(secondNumberList)
```

Prints:

```
[3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 2, 4, 0, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 9, 9, 12, 12, 18, 19, 18, 9]
```

EDIT: Version with `list.insert` (Thanks to @Chris_Rands):

```
for i, v in zip(indexNumberList, firstNumberList):
    secondNumberList.insert(i, v)
```

Comment: `secondNumberList.insert(i, v)`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yes, added to my answer. Thanks! (It's more efficient than slicing)

Answer (score 0):

If you have numpy installed, this is nicer to read and follow along:

```
import numpy as np 

indexNumberList = [1, 2, 5, 8]
firstNumberList = [0, 0, 0, 0]
secondNumberList = [ 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 9, 9, 12, 12, 18, 19, 18, 9]

new_array = np.ones(len(secondNumberList) + len(firstNumberList)) * np.nan

new_array[indexNumberList] = firstNumberList
new_array[np.where(np.isnan(new_array))] = secondNumberList

list(new_array)
```

Comment: Though it is slower. 143 microseconds vs. 80.1 microseconds.